# Update a table with scope identity from new inserted row

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table in which I need to update one column with ticketnumbers.
These ticketnumbers are created in another table where it is an identity field.

This code doesn't work. Why?

```
UPDATE sheet10
SET [TicketNummer] = (INSERT INTO ticketnummers (AangemaaktOp, aangemaaktdoor,verwijderd,afgewezen) VALUES ('2014-01-20 15:00:00',100,0,0) SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() )
where isnumeric([TicketNummer]) = 0
```

What am I doing wrong?

rg.
Eric

Comment: What is the `ISNUMERIC()` test really doing? Are you setting any rows in Sheet10 where the ticketnumber is null to the value of the new ticketnumber? Isn't that a bit dangerous? I think you should also show how you got these rows into sheet10 and why/how they are related to the row you just inserted into ticketnummers. PS what you are doing wrong is called "inventing syntax." :-)

Comment: What is the JOINING field for the 2 tables? And why?

You can INSERT in one table and UPDATE another using "Composable DML", but why does a row exists in the `sheet10` table already for what will be a new row in `ticketnummers`

Comment: The table with the name sheet10 has 900 rows. The update is the first step for me. In this table the cells of ticketnummer are empty, hence the IsNummeric function. After this column has been filled, I use this table to update two other tables.

Comment: What purpose does this sheet10 table serve? What information does it store about the tickets that the tickets table doesn't hold? Why does it already have 900 rows if you haven't inserted the 900 tickets yet?

Comment: It's a list of information the client wants me to put in those newly created tickets.

Comment: But why two tables? Why can't this information be stored with the ticket numbers?

Comment: does that matter for my question?

Comment: @Eric it could, because it could make solving the problem a lot easier, and your database design a lot more practical.

Answer (score 2):

Composable DML should let you INSERT **only** if the UPDATE has a row matching

However...

- how do you correlate rows?
- What happens for concurrent inserts?
- What if multiple rows have no TicketNummer value in sheet10
- and many other questions

In summary, this is *possible* even if I'd never actually do it given the design questions

```
UPDATE
    sheet10
SET
    TicketNummer = (
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        (
        INSERT INTO ticketnummers (AangemaaktOp, aangemaaktdoor,verwijderd,afgewezen)
        OUTPUT INSERTED.IDColumn
        VALUES ('2014-01-20 15:00:00', 100, 0, 0)
        ) X
)
WHERE
   ISNULL(TicketNummer, 0) = 0;
```

Comment: +1 however I still have no idea what the OP is actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: @gbn: Your code produces this error: A nested INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE statement is not allowed in a SELECT statement that is not the immediate source of rows for an INSERT statement.

Comment: @Aaron: The application is a ticketing system. I use the ticketnummers table to produce a ticketnumber and that number is the reference to the two other tables. My client wants me to create 900 new tickets with an upload. This list does not have the ticketnumber because it needs to be created first. So I want to create the ticketnumber, then update the upload table and then insert tickets in the two tables with that data.

Comment: @Eric: well, perhaps describe your problem more clearly and I can update this answer

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use INSERT in this way. It has to be statement on its own.

Basically you have to perform this operation in 2 steps:

```
INSERT INTO ticketnummers (AangemaaktOp, aangemaaktdoor,verwijderd,afgewezen) VALUES ('2014-01-20 15:00:00',100,0,0);

UPDATE sheet10
    SET [TicketNummer] = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
where ISNULL([TicketNummer], 0) = 0
```

Comment: I'm guessing the INSERT should only happen if the sheet10.ticketnummber is null...

Comment: Or update will happen for rows with TicketNummer==0 (or numeric) It's kind of difficult to say.

Comment: So I need to do this for each of the 900 records in table Sheet10?

Comment: Well, it's now clear what you want to achieve @Eric. If you have 900 rows in this table and try to create ticked number for each then you would have to loop over those or create function to create tickets and return their value

Comment: So I could do something like SET ticketnummer = SomeFunction()? this function would then do the insert and returns the identity scope?

Comment: Yes, exactly this way

Comment: Ok, I have now created the stored procedure (functions with insert into are not allowed). SET ticketnummer = getnumber results in an error: Invalid column name 'getnumber'.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45654/discussion-between-rafal-ziolkowski-and-eric)

Comment: You should use dbo.getnumber() use schema prefix and brackets.

Comment: Rafal, I'm in the chat part.